# Why won't GCC auto-vectorize this loop?

Tags: c, gcc, vectorization

I have the following C program (a simplification of my actual use case which exhibits the same behavior)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    const float * __restrict__ const input = malloc(20000*sizeof(float));
    float * __restrict__ const output = malloc(20000*sizeof(float));

    unsigned int pos=0;
    while(1) {
            unsigned int rest=100;
            for(unsigned int i=pos;i<pos+rest; i++) {
                    output[i] = input[i] * 0.1;
            }

            pos+=rest;            
            if(pos>10000) {
                    break;
            }
    }
}
```

When I compile with

```
 -O3 -g -Wall -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=5 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -march=native -mtune=native --std=c99 -fPIC -ffast-math
```

I get the output

```
main.c:10: note: not vectorized: unhandled data-ref
```

where 10 is the line of the inner for loop.  When I looked up why it might say this, it seemed to be saying that the pointers could be aliased, but they can't be in my code, as I have the __restrict keyword.  They also suggested including the -msse flags, but they don't seem to do anything either.  Any help?

Comment: What version gcc?  A working example might be useful as well, as a hacked up version vectorized when I tried it with 4.4.5

Comment: could you post example code that compiles? when I filled in some dummy values, the loop was vectorized...

Comment: I've updated the example to be compilable.  It still won't vectorize.  I'm using "gcc (Debian 4.4.5-10) 4.4.5"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly seems like a bug.  In the following, equivalent functions, `foo()` is vectorised but `bar()` is not, when compiling for an x86-64 target:

```
void foo(const float * restrict input, float * restrict output)
{
    unsigned int pos;
    for (pos = 0; pos < 10100; pos++)
        output[pos] = input[pos] * 0.1;
}

void bar(const float * restrict input, float * restrict output)
{
    unsigned int pos;
    unsigned int i;
    for (pos = 0; pos <= 10000; pos += 100)
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            output[pos + i] = input[pos + i] * 0.1;
}
```

Adding the `-m32` flag, to compile for an x86 target instead, causes both functions to be vectorised.

Comment: Thank you!  I am on a 64 bit platform!  doing -m32 makes it work perfectly.  I'm filing a bug report now.  The other answers are great, but really are just workarounds, as this should work with no modification.

Comment: Note that the 32 bit executable may be much slower than the non-vectorized 64, so unless your goal is purely "use SSE" you should profile your whole application.

Comment: Thanks Ben,  I'm actually not using this to compile my code, but just to file the bug report.  I can get it to vectorize correctly on 64 bit by just rearranging things a little.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't like the outer loop format which is preventing it from understanding the inner loop.  I can get it to vectorize if I just fold it into a single loop:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    const float * __restrict__ input = malloc(20000*sizeof(float));
    float * __restrict__ output = malloc(20000*sizeof(float));

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<=10100; i++) {
            output[i] = input[i] * 0.1f;
    }
}
```

(note that I didn't think too hard about how to properly translate the pos+rest limit into a single for loop condition, it may be wrong)

You might be able to take advantage of this by putting a simplified inner loop into a function which you call with pointers and a count.  Even when it is inlined again it may work fine.  This is assuming you deleted parts of your `while()` loop that I have just simplified away but you need to retain.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
const float * __restrict__ input = ...;
float * __restrict__ output = ...;
```

experiment a bit by changing things around:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    const float * __restrict__ input = new float[20000];
    float * __restrict__  output = new float[20000];

    unsigned int pos=0;
    while(1) {
        unsigned int rest=100;
        output += pos;
        input += pos;
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<rest; ++i) {
            output[i] = input[i] * 0.1;
        }

        pos+=rest;
        if(pos>10000) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

g++ -O3 -g -Wall -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=7 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -c test.cpp

test.cpp:14: note: versioning for alias required: can't determine dependence between *D.4096_24 and *D.4095_21
test.cpp:14: note: mark for run-time aliasing test between *D.4096_24 and *D.4095_21
test.cpp:14: note: Alignment of access forced using versioning.
test.cpp:14: note: Vectorizing an unaligned access.
test.cpp:14: note: vect_model_load_cost: unaligned supported by hardware.
test.cpp:14: note: vect_model_load_cost: inside_cost = 2, outside_cost = 0 .
test.cpp:14: note: vect_model_simple_cost: inside_cost = 2, outside_cost = 0 .
test.cpp:14: note: vect_model_simple_cost: inside_cost = 2, outside_cost = 1 .
test.cpp:14: note: vect_model_simple_cost: inside_cost = 1, outside_cost = 0 .
test.cpp:14: note: vect_model_store_cost: inside_cost = 1, outside_cost = 0 .
test.cpp:14: note: cost model: Adding cost of checks for loop versioning to treat misalignment.

test.cpp:14: note: cost model: Adding cost of checks for loop versioning aliasing.

test.cpp:14: note: Cost model analysis:
  Vector inside of loop cost: 8
  Vector outside of loop cost: 6
  Scalar iteration cost: 5
  Scalar outside cost: 1
  prologue iterations: 0
  epilogue iterations: 0
  Calculated minimum iters for profitability: 2

test.cpp:14: note:   Profitability threshold = 3

test.cpp:14: note: Vectorization may not be profitable.
test.cpp:14: note: create runtime check for data references *D.4096_24 and *D.4095_21
test.cpp:14: note: created 1 versioning for alias checks.

test.cpp:14: note: LOOP VECTORIZED.
test.cpp:4: note: vectorized 1 loops in function.

Compilation finished at Wed Feb 16 19:17:59
```

Comment: What is the rationale for this?

Comment: @Oli just a guess, may be his compiler doesnt like extra const or `__restrict` form

Comment: @Jeremy see my update, it does not like runtime starting bound.  my guess it thinks pos might be aliased somehow.